# typescript правила работа утилиты

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

```
type n<T> = T & {}
```

ни как не могу понять почему так работает
то есть пересечение пустого объекта и типа содержащего `null` `undefined` удаляет их и возвращает типы без них

Comment: А теперь подробнее…

Comment: Вот код Nonullable<T> = T & {} , для утилиты которая из типа удаляет undefined и null , как он работат тоесть почему пересечение с {} дает такой результат

Answer (score 3):

В `Typescript` символ `|` расширяет тип, а `&` сужает.

Если сравнивать с `SQL`, то `&` действует подобно `JOIN` , а `|` как `UNION`

Так же можно сравнить с одноименными битовыми операциями `&` и `|`, где `&` имеет более жесткие правила чем `|`

*Все вышесказанное это лишь аналогии которые возможно помогут запомнить правила для `Typescript`.*

Для лучшего понимания вышесказанного приведу иллюстрацию и код:

```
type T1 =  number | string  // расширяем
type T2 =  string | boolean // расширяем
type T3 =  T1 & T2 // сужаем

let t3: T3 = "string"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если мы посмотрим что из себя представляет тип объявленный как `{}` он будет `nonullable`, т.е. в нем есть все типы кроме `null` и `undefined` именно по этой причине типы связаные с ним через пересечения будут лишены тех же свойств.

По этой причине переменные `k6` и `k7` инициализируются с ошибкой.

```
type Nonullable<T> = T & {} // {} все типы кроме `null` и `undefined`

let k0: Nonullable<number> = 123
let k1: Nonullable<string> = "null"
let k2: Nonullable<boolean> = true
let k3: Nonullable<symbol> = Symbol("dsa")
let k4: Nonullable<object> = {} 
let k5: Nonullable<bigint> = 100n // ES2020
let k6: Nonullable<undefined> = undefined; // ошибка
let k7: Nonullable<null> = null // ошибка
```

Comment: Более менее понял спасибо

Comment: @fr33man если ответ правильный, отметьте его галочкой. А за хороший ответ можете и "голос за" дать.